# Independent dimensions for QML-Items

Tags: qt, qml

I am using `QQmlApplicationEngine` and therefore have one `root` element and `Item`-s. Because I have one `root` file, to which all the methods connected from C++ (but still accessible in whole .qml directory) I can't make the other `Item`-s be independet from the dimension settings of the root. So if I make `minimumwidth` of the value 300, so the other `Item`-s going to have the same `minimumWidth` too.
The quesstion is, whether it's possible to make them independent from main.qml and be able set others dimensions.

Here is some code to make you idea what I am talking about:

main.cpp:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("mqttClient",mqttClient);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("math",math);



    engine.load(url);
```

main.qml:

```
Window {
    id:root
    width: 400
    height: 300
    minimumWidth:  960
    minimumHeight: 420
   
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Dampfmaschine Client")

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: "LoginPage.qml"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    Component{
        id: login
        LoginPage{}
    }

    Component{
        id: measure_page2
        MeasurePage2{}
    }

    function load_page(page){
        switch(page){
        case 'MeasurePage':
            stackView.push(measure_page2);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you can set `root.width = 600` from the `load_page` function, if you like?

Comment: @Amfasis well I thought about this, but really interested in other ways of implementing it :D. Apropos thanks for the commenting

Comment: ok, then please make that clear in the question

Comment: Maybe [QQuickView.resizeMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickview.html#resizeMode-prop) set to `QQuickView::SizeViewToRootObject` can solve the issue.

Comment: What do you actually want to happen visually? Root window should expand/contract based on which page is selected, or you want it to have scroll bars if your page is larger than window? Or something else? A simple mockup picture could really help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Binding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) type in QML to set a binding which can be optional. I propose to add some property in your pages, for example:

```
LoginPage {

    property int windowWidth : 200
    property int windowHeight : 300
}
```

Then in main, you put the Binding

```
Window {
    id:root
    width: 400
    height: 300
    minimumWidth:  960
    minimumHeight: 420

    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Dampfmaschine Client")

    Binding {
        target: root
        property: "width"
        value: stackView.currentItem.windowWidth
    }

    Binding {
        target: root
        property: "height"
        value: stackView.currentItem.windowHeight
    }

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: "LoginPage.qml"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    Component{
        id: login
        LoginPage{}
    }

    Component{
        id: measure_page2
        MeasurePage2{}
    }

    function load_page(page){
        switch(page){
        case 'MeasurePage':
            stackView.push(measure_page2);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

This way, the window will always be bound to the current item of the stackView and you don't have to look after it.

Optionally you can also use `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` from the pages, leading to even less maintenance (but possibly some headaches with weird pages)